# How do I disable notifications in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, notifications, calendar

I've found that Outlook notifications are quite a pain and I've tried to disable them but I can't find a setting anywhere. Does anyone know how to disable the calendar notifications (separate windows that shows up) on Office 365 installed locally on Mac OS 10.13 and Windows 10 (Outlook for Mac v16.16 and Outlook 2016 respectively)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I’ve flagged this question because it’s not about programming, better fit for superuser SE

Comment: Good point, I just posted it on SE and I'll delete it here.